# Problems with using tensorflow on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, model, google-colaboratory, detection

I'm new to all this. Can someone please tell me what's going on? So how can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXJsL.png)

Basically, I want to use tf, but I'm stuck. Because I've never used it before.
I would like to use it with my detection model.

Thank you everyone for all your help.
With respect, Good luck to all of you.

Comment: Hello Grandpa, welcome to stackfoverlow ! Could you copy-paste the code (and errors) you have in your image so it's more accessible, and easier to archive in case the link stops working ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whats your keras version? e.g. use `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.keras.__version__)"`

Comment: Thank you all so much, I did it.
I edited the libraries to look like this:
`import tensorflow as tf
from keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.layers import (Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D,
                          BatchNormalization, SeparableConv2D, MaxPooling2D,
                          DepthwiseConv2D, AveragePooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, LearningRateScheduler
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import AUC`
thanks agin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `from tensorflow.keras.layers` you can do `from keras.layers`, same for the other instance of importing from `tensorflow.keras`.

In fact in your screenshot you already have a line importing `from keras.layers`.